# Change color of footer section and remove underlines from it

Tags: html, css

Footer section tags is showing blue color and also I want to remove line under the li tags. I will paste further code of HTML or CSS if needed.I am pasting HTML and CSS code of footer.

My HTML & CSS

```css
footer {
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top: 8px solid #2d2132;
}
#footer ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer">

    <ul class="footer" id="footersection">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: @GCYrillus ?? I didn't get you properly. I am sorry.

Comment: @GCyrillus That's not how his code is. The `|` is a separate `li` element. OP, I recommend you fix the formatting.

Comment: Thanks! So for putting | between footer icons. what should I do?

Comment: Please let me know how to format. I didn't know about this. Usually I do like this. Thanks!

Comment: I've put each `li` on its own line. It'll be less confusing now. I don't get why you added all the pipes though. There's no need for them.

Comment: I need to make a design according to mockups and it shows me there in footer section. if possible please correct one line of code to make me understand. Thanks!

Comment: I'm talking about the white pipes(`|` symbols) that you put up. If your background is white, you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer a {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Michiel mentioned, the following works..

```
#footer a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Your vertical lines are there if you highlight your text, you just need to change their default color in your CSS.  Alternatively you could create a row with 7 columns in CSS rather than having all these messy li tags.

Answer (score 0):

If above answers don't work, try making the custom settings important:

```
#footer a {
   color: black !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is tricky; it just overrides settings in other CSS rules. Randomly using them to 'make what you want happen' is considered bad coding practice. Also they make debugging difficult.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but sometimes !important, really is the only way to get something done.